# Hexo clean, cannot get /

Tags: hexo

When I call Hexo clean in powershell it shows
Deleted Database
Delete public folder

When I call Hexo generate and Hexo Server --open at localhost:4000 the site is broken and only display the text "Cannot GET /".

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In _config.yml under index generator path was set as '' and not generating the index.html file. Simply add the path where you want your index.html to generate to.

In my case it was adding the path as '\' which generated it into the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

If not exists, create an empty file called `index.md` inside the path `/source/_posts/`.